# Infimum of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

How do I find $\inf$ and $\sup$   of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ for  $x\gt0$ ?

IMO it's quite easy to guess, but since I am on Math studies everything needs to be formal and I am not allowed to use things like derivatives just yet.

Any help or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: To find the $\inf$ without derivatives is simply impossible. The $\inf$ is a minimum and it is attained at the least positive root of $x=\tan x$, i.e. close to $x=4.5$. In particular $$\inf_{x>0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=-0.217234\ldots$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I succeded without derivatives :))

Comment: @Raffaele: no, you did not. You only found an approximation of such $\inf$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $x>0$ we have

$\sin x < x < \tan x$ a

as $\sin x>0$ we can divide the previous inequality by $\sin x$ and get

$$1 < \frac{x}{\sin x}< \frac{1}{\cos x}$$
reversing the fractions we have
$$\cos x < \frac{\sin x}{x} < 1$$

therefore as the minimum of $\cos x$ is $-1$ we have

$$-1<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1$$

So $1$ is clearly a sup, never attained on the function domain.

The inequality can be also taken from another point of view

we have $-1\le \sin x\le +1$ and therefore For any $x>0$

$$-\frac{1}{x}\le \frac{\sin x}{x}\le \frac{1}{x}$$

Therefore the minimum of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is close to the $x$ where

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=-\frac{1}{x}$$

that is when $\sin x = -1\to x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$

$$\frac{\sin{\frac{3\pi}{2}}}{{\frac{3\pi}{2}}}=-\frac{2}{3\pi}\approx -0.2122$$

Look the image at the bottom. The actual minimum is about $\color{red}{-0.217234}$ and is different because of course at the minimum the tangent is horizontal and no point on the hyperbola has an horizontal tangent. The actual minimum can be found setting zero the derivative of the function.

Hope this helps
$$...$$

[image]
[image]

Comment: The minimum of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ **does not** occur at $x=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ but at $x=4.49341\ldots<\frac{3\pi}{2}$. Indeed $$\inf_{x>0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=-0.217234\ldots \color{red}{<} -0.2122 $$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You are right. Hyperbola has not horizontal tangent...

Comment: @Raffaele
Didn't You restrict domain to those x which make these inequalities $\sin(x)\gt x \gt \tan(x)$  true ? In this case shouldn't the final answer be somewhere in this interval?

Comment: $\sin x<x<\tan x $ is true for any $x>0$. Look at the graph I made for you https://imgur.com/a/yM4bI